# How to display tableview within a cell of other tableview?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I want to display a `UITableView` within the cell of another `UITableView` without using custom cell.

I tried to display it using a **customCell**, it is working but that is not convenient for me. So I would like to present the `UITableView` within a cell of other `UITableView` without using customCell

Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a custom cell for this kind of thing. I don't think there is a way to implement it without a `UITableViewCell` subclass.

Look at this tutorial for some inspiration:

[How To Make An Interface with Horizontal Tables Like The Pulse News App](http://www.raywenderlich.com/4680/how-to-make-an-interface-with-horizontal-tables-like-the-pulse-news-app-part-1)